# In June–July 1967? Between June–July 1967?

Tags: prepositions, dates, dashes

Which is correct and which is not?

1. In June--July 1967, there were...
2. Between June--July 1967, there were...
3. Between June and July 1967, there were...

If I want to use "June--July 1967", how can I express?

Comment: A dash does not mean "and", so option 2 makes no sense.

Comment: In the June - July 1967 timeframe ...

Comment: Your vagueness makes your question hard to answer. There were ***what***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even say what you're trying to express. An approximate date? A few events within a given range? A set of inclusive dates?

For an approximate date, I would use *around/or*:

> Around June or July of 1967, the storm hit.

For a few events within a range, I might use *during/and* (or perhaps *between/and*):

> During June and July of 1967, it only rained five times.
>   Between June and July of 1967, it only rained five times.

To allude to the entire range of dates, I would suggest *in/and*:

> In June and July of 1967, the weather was exceptionally hot.

For a longer range, I would use *from/through*:

> From June through September of 1967, there was a severe drought.

Generally speaking, I would avoid using a dash. (Again, though, you haven't given us much to analyze). There are some contexts – like tombstones and journals – where dashes are appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Though the context is not clear, I would recommend referring to the dictionary meaning of Between. It fits in properly, if I assume your sentence is about a range or a shared/common aspect **during** June-July 1967.

```
 "BETWEEN is used to indicate a range or something that is shared or combined."
```

And again, why not "during".

June-July:
To describe sequences of dates/weeks/months, use of a hyphen (with no spaces between the hyphen and the characters) instead of the word “to” or “through” appears to me as an acceptable writing norm.